# Writing loop in SASS that increments various variables

Tags: function, loops, sass, increment

I have a base class which I need to increment by 100:

```
.myclass.link-1 + a {
   color: red;
}
```

So when my class has a link number of 1 (`.link-1`), it needs to target the first adjacent sibling with an `<a>` tag.
But when my link has a number of e.g. 5, it needs to target the adjacent siblings 1 to 5 with  tags:

```
.myclass.link-5 + a,
.myclass.link-5 + a + a,
.myclass.link-5 + a + a + a,
.myclass.link-5 + a + a + a + a,
.myclass.link-5 + a + a + a + a + a {
   color: red;
}
```

Is there any way to write a SASS loop for this case?
I need it from 1 to 100, so it needs to create 100 different rules.